# How to get rid of space surrounding Material UI checkbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

[image]

The problem it creates is obvious. Even if the user clicks outside of the checkbox, it will still change the box value.

Goal is to remove that space.

```
            <FormControlLabel
              style={{ height: "25px" }}
              control={<Checkbox size="small" style={{ width: "20px" }} />}
              label={
                <Box component="div" fontSize={10}>
                  label
                </Box>
              }
            />
```

Note the `width: "20px"` has no effect.

Comment: could you please provide your current code?

Comment: sorry, code added now

Comment: outside FormControlLabel or only outside Checkbox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Checkbox has a default padding. You could remove that by passing a custom style

```
<Checkbox size="small" style={{ width: "20px", padding:0 }} />
```

Although I'd recommend using material-ui's makeStyles API and pass a className.
https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#makestyles-styles-options-hook

Here is the example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 20,
    padding: 0,
  },
})

const CustomizedCheckbox = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
      <Checkbox className={classes.root}/>
  )
}

export default CustomizedCheckbox
```

Answer (score 1):

As for MUI 5 you can use `sx` props

```
<Checkbox
    sx={{pl: 0}}
    // rest props
/>
```

`pl` means `padding-left`, thus `pr` is `padding-right` etc.